# Azure Data Warehouse backup to SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have an **azure data warehouse** with some data. I need to do some performance tests on **SQL database** with the same content as on my data warehouse.

Is that possible to create a backup from **data warehouse** and use it to create **SQL server database**? How can I achieve it? I didn't find anything I can use in a documentation. There are some ways to migrate from a database to a data warehouse. From the portal I can see an option to restore a **data warehouse** to another **data warehouse**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that using a backup-related technology, sorry.

The best option is to use Azure Data Factory and the COPY task, with Azure Synapse as your source and Azure SQL as your destination.

Comment: Thank you. Worked as expected